Solving a Symmetric, Nonlinear System of Equations involving Trig Functions
During my work, I've encountered the following system of equations.
$A = x_a \cos(\phi_a) + x_b \cos(\phi_b)$
$B = x_a \sin(\phi_a) + x_b \sin(\phi_b)$
$C = x_a \cos(2\phi_a) + x_b \cos(2\phi_b)$
$D = x_a \sin(2\phi_a) + x_b \sin(2\phi_b)$
The goal is to isolate $x_a, x_b$ in terms of ${A,B,C,D}$, and I'm having a really hard time finding a closed form solution.
If I relax the requirements by allowing $\phi_a = 0$, then I have
$A = x_a  + x_b \cos(\phi_b)$
$B = x_b \sin(\phi_b)$
$C = x_a + x_b \cos(2\phi_b)$
$D = x_b \sin(2\phi_b),$
This is much more tractable. I find, defining the auxiliary variable $\xi = 2 B^2 + B D - D^2$, 
$x_a = A -D \frac{B (A-C) }{\xi}$
$x_b = 2 B\frac{B (A - C)}{\xi}$
But I cannot seem to solve the general problem. Is it impossible? Is there a way to exploit the symmetry?

Did you try using complex number? Namely consider $A+Bi, C+Di$.

Are $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$ fixed ?

Yes, they are fixed but unknown.
